# store datagridview column value in a variable

Tags: c#

I want to store the column values (to be precise two column values in two variables). How this can be achieved. Any sample code will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to store only 2 column values (from what control?) Maybe you can show us some code.

Comment: What do you mean by column values ? all cells under a column !

Comment: I have two columns (with only one row of data populated), namely Called Number and Callee Number. I have to select the two columns and store them in two variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var column1 = dataGrid.Rows[0].Cells["Called Number"].Value;
var column2 = dataGrid.Rows[0].Cells["Callee Number"].Value;
```

If you know the specific type (String, int, etc.) you can do some sort of conversion if you want:

```
int column1 = Int32.Parse(dataGrid.Rows[0].Cells["Called Number"].Value.ToString());
int column2 = Int32.Parse(dataGrid.Rows[0].Cells["Callee Number"].Value.ToString());
```